# Print both landscape and portrait in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How can I print the first 2 pages in portrait orientation and the next 2 pages in landscape orientation?

I was try setup on page setup to landscape but not work. Does anyone have a solution to the problem?
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Designer has a built in option to change page layout in the Section properties:
[image]

Comment: I did that but when I choose landscape on the bottom 2 pages, it's still in potrait

Comment: It's not a page-based option. It's a section-based option.
You can create sub-section (e.g. GF2a, GF2b, etc.), assign different layouts to each, and control which copy (and hence which orientation is visible using an expression to control the 'Suppress' property.

Answer (score 0):

1. Design your report in Crystal Reports: First, you need to design your report using Crystal Reports. Create a report that includes the content you want to print on the first 2 pages in portrait mode and the next 2 pages in landscape mode.
2. Install Crystal Reports runtime: Ensure that you have installed the appropriate Crystal Reports runtime on the machine where you'll be running the application.
3. Integrate Crystal Reports in C#: In your C# application, you can use the Crystal Reports SDK to load and print the report.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public class CustomReportPrinter
{
    private int currentPage = 1;

    public void Print()
    {
        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        reportDocument.Load("path_to_your_report_file.rpt"); // Replace with the actual path to your Crystal Report file

        // Set up the PrintDocument object for custom printing
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPageHandler);

        // Set the Crystal Report's PrintOptions to use the custom PrintDocument
        reportDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

        // Start printing
        reportDocument.PrintToPrinter(printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies, false, 0, 0);
    }

    private void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your content for the first 2 pages (currentPage 1 and 2) in portrait orientation
        if (currentPage <= 2)
        {
            // Add your code here to draw the content for the first 2 pages in portrait mode
            // Example:
            // e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " + currentPage, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(100, 100));
            // ...

            // Move to the next page
            currentPage++;

            // Check if there are more pages to print
            e.HasMorePages = currentPage <= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Your content for the next 2 pages (currentPage 3 and 4) in landscape orientation
            // Add your code here to draw the content for the next 2 pages in landscape mode
            // Example:
            // e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " + currentPage, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new PointF(100, 100));
            // ...

            // Move to the next page
            currentPage++;

            // Check if there are more pages to print
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> In this code, we use the Crystal Reports ReportDocument class to load the report file. We then set up a custom PrintDocument object for printing. The PrintPageHandler method handles the content drawing for each page, similar to the previous example without Crystal Reports.Please make sure you have installed and referenced the appropriate Crystal Reports runtime in your project before using the Crystal Reports components. Also, replace "path_to_your_report_file.rpt" with the actual path to your Crystal Report file in the Print method.This way, you can integrate Crystal Reports with C# and handle the page orientation as required for your report printing.